# Two electrons Gaussian Integrals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, atomic-physics, computational-physics, molecules

I want to implement a Hartree-Fock C++ program for my blog. I found on 'Mathematica Journal' a set of three papers that describe the evaluation of Gaussian molecular integrals. The problem is that they are only for overlap, kinetic and electron-nucleus. The more complex ones, electron-electron are not handled.

I have enough information to solve the two electrons integral by 'brute force' but it's going to be slow that way. I want to use a recursive scheme, at least Obara–Saika, if not the improved scheme of Head-Gordon and Pople.

I cannot find enough information about it on internet to suffice for an implementation. Does anybody know if there is such resource available online?

Comment: Does section 3.2.3 [here](https://rsc.anu.edu.au/~pgill/papers/045Review.pdf) help?

Comment: Thank you for the link. Actually 3.8 and 3.9 sections are more helpful, I already know how to solve it for the s orbitals. Unfortunately I don't think those sections (only a couple of pages) are complete enough to allow me implement the recursion algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I ended up in using the Hamilton and Schaefer method. The paper than helped me the most is: http://theory.rutgers.edu/~giese/notes/HSERILib.pdf I found several papers about solving the integrals, but this one was the one that was the most useful.

The program is now open source, available at: https://github.com/aromanro/HartreeFock

I have a description for it on my blog: http://compphys.go.ro/the-hartree-fock-program/ I have there more links to papers and also some notes on the theory.

Hopefully this turns out to be helpful for others looking for info.

Answer (score 2):

When I had to evaluate the two-electron integrals some years ago, I found two practical alternatives.

The first and pragmatic one is to use the routines from the program  [Py-Quante](http://pyquante.sourceforge.net/#two-electron-integrals).  They are written in C++ and cover three different algorithms, among them the Head-Gordon method, the Rys quadrature and Huzinaga's method. The license of PyQuate allows you to use and modify these C++-programs, so you can start directly.

the second and more elabourate method is to do it by yourself. For this, grab the book "Molecular Electronic Quantum Chemistry" (which is anyways the best book in Quantum Chemistry imo), and consider chapter 9 which is exclusively devoted to the calculation of two-electron integrals. It contains the evaluations in a rather clear explanation which is quite appropriate for an algorithmic translation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot accept it, though, because what I needed is information about implementation... not from a book. It takes time to get it and if it's the same book I've heard about before, it's also expensive. I also did not want to reuse some code implemented by others. I managed to implement them finally, by using a pdf from internet about a library implementation, HSERILib. The code will hopefully be soon available from http://compphys.go.ro . I guess I should answer my own question to help others that look for something similar, I might do that later...

Comment: The cited book contains all the information you are looking for (in particular: the algorithms of Obara-Saika, McMurchie-Davidson and the Rys quadrature).

Comment: I believe you, but what I wanted was an online resource, not an expensive book. It doesn't matter anymore, I found the needed information, the program appears to work. I implemented both restricted and unrestricted Hartree-Fock. The H2O test passed nicely for the restricted case. I'm using both STO-3G and STO-6G (for now) in the program and it seems I'm getting the same results as other programs give.

Comment: Unless you want to hold them physically in your hand, there are no "expensive books" these days ;-)